# How do I remember a React-Router URL parameter when navigating away and then back to a page?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router

### Issue:

I have a React app that uses React-Router-DOM for hash-routing. The app has a main navigation bar with `Home` and `About`. The `Home` content has a sub-nav bar with `A`, `B`, and `C`.

When navigating to `www.mysite.com/#/home/` the router defaults (redirects) to `www.mysite.com/#/home/A`.

When navigating from `/#/about` to `/#/home` via the `Home` nav-link, I want the router to remember which sub-route was last used. Currently, navigating to back to home with the `Home` nav link, returns to `#/home/A`

### Example:

1. enter URL www.mysite.com in browser ==> renders `/home/#/A`
2. use sub-nav menu under `Home` to select `B` ===> renders `/#/home/B`
3. use main nav menu to select `About` ==> renders `/#/about`
4. use main nav menu to select `Home` ==> renders `/#/home/B`

### Structure

```
<App>
    <header>
        <NavLink to="/home">home</NavLink>
        <NavLink to="/contact">contact</NavLink>
    </header>

    <section>
        <Switch>
            <Redirect exact from="/" to="/home/A" />

            <Route path="/home">
                <div>
                    <sub-header>
                        <NavLink to="/home/A">A</NavLink>
                        <NavLink to="/home/B">B</NavLink>
                        <NavLink to="/home/C">C</NavLink>
                    </sub-header>

                    <div>
                        ... content for home
                        <Switch>
                            <Route path="/home/:id" component={ChildComponentThatUsesID}>
                        </Switch>
                    </div>

                </div>
            </Route>

            <Route path="/about"> ... </Route>              

        </Switch>
    </section>
</App>
```

### Notes

I know that I will need to change the Redirect, that is just there for convenience. I also know that I will have to change the `<NavLink to="/home">` to somehow incorporate a variable property or state that will be set when using one of the sub-menu links, but I don't know how to go about doing this.

Answer (score 0):

i've never try this type of things but React Router has the history "component/props". See the documentation here : 
https://github.com/ReactTraining/history#properties

Answer (score 0):

Use react-router's internal state.

```
const location = {
  pathname: '/somewhere',
  state: { fromDashboard: true }
}

<Redirect to={location}/>
```

You can access it later through `this.props.location.state`.

Comment: How would I go about using this internal state to save the location when navigating away from /home/xxx?